# Android Action Bar (inflated one) and back Button

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, action

I am using Fragment A and fragment B ,I am going from fragment A to fragment B. In fragment B i am inflating Action bar (it only need in fragment B) when I press back button I need to go to fragment A  without inflating action bar.

how could it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In first fragment `onCreate()` method use:

`getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide()` or `getActivity().getActionBar().hide()`

And in second Fragment `onCreate()` method use:

`getActivity().getSupportActionBar().show()` or `getActivity().getActionBar().show()`

Comment: the thing is iam using default action bar for fragment A so i cant hide it i need it...(thank you Sayem for quick replay)